# Query dataframe using index value between index entries

Tags: python, pandas

I'm reading temperature entries stored in a file.
Each entry is generated when the temperature value changes, so it is not stored in regular intervals.

An example of the data could be as follows:

```
timestamp  | temperature
-----------+------------
1477400000 | 31
1477400001 | 31.5
1477400003 | 32
1477400010 | 31.5
1477400200 | 32
1477400201 | 32.5
```

I would need a fast way to get the temperature at any timestamp, **even if it is not in the index**. For instance, temperature at `1477400002` would be `31.5`, but `1477400002` is not in the index.

For sake of easier reproducibility, the same dataframe may be generated as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'temperature': [31, 31.5, 32, 31.5, 32, 32.5]},
                  index=[1477400000, 1477400001, 1477400003, 1477400010, 1477400200, 1477400201])
```

Comment: Why should it return `31.5` rather than `32`?

Comment: @kiril, Does the index values repeat itself as shown in your mcve?

Comment: It should return 31.5 because the value 32 was set before that timestamp

Comment: oh, no sorry, it was a mistake, I'll update it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the index is sorted, you can use `np.searchsorted` to return the ordinal position and use `iloc` to index into the df:

```
In [84]:
df.iloc[max(0, np.searchsorted(df.index, 1477400002 ) -1)]

Out[84]:
temperature    31.5
Name: 1477400001, dtype: float64
```

Here I subtract 1 from the result of `np.searchsorted` to return the lower bound, additionally to protect against the situation where it returns the first entry I also calc the `max` between `0` and the returned value so if you tried to find `1477400000` then this will still return the first entry

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) method and set it's arg `nearest=pad` to
find the previous index value in case if no match is found. Then, use [`DF.get_value`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.get_value.html) to retrieve the value at the index pointed by the aforementioned operation by accessing the name attribute and the column of interest, temperature as shown:

***Demo:***

```
df.get_value(df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(1477400002, method='pad')].name, 'temperature')
# 31.5

df.get_value(df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(1477400003, method='pad')].name, 'temperature')
# 32.0
```

It is assumed that the query would begin after the first index, as you would want the previous value at any given point in time.

***Timings:***

```
%timeit df.get_value(df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(1477400002, method='pad')].name, 'temperature')
1000 loops, best of 3: 164 µs per loop
```

Comment: Can you add timings?

Comment: Yeah, I've added it. But EdChum's answer is twice as fast compared to mine, although it gives you previous results if the query contains a match already whereas mine returns the same value.

Comment: Unfortunately it fail in this key `print (df.get_value(df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(1477300999, method='pad')].name, 'temperature'))
`

Comment: Hmmm, I think `get_value` is not necessary - use `(df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(1477400002, method='pad')])`

Comment: Yup, I do know that. That's why I mentioned the query to be greater than the first index value. Else, you get a *keyError* as a result of padding. If the OP requires it, you can always add a try/except and supply `method=nearest` which can handle it correctly.

Comment: Ok, I try similar solution +1

Comment: I've also measured the execution time and EdChum is twice as fast in several scenarios. Although the opposite it is proved, I'll mark it as better solution